# How can I specify the position of vertices to create an object using Python?

Tags: python, mesh, vertices

I have generated a large matrix with the (x,y) positions of all 4 vertices of a rectangle, using a Python script. It's called Matrix1, and has the dimensions (265,2,4)- 265 rectangles, 4 vertices with their x coordinate in the first row, and the y co-ordinate in the second row respectively.

As I am new to Blender, I am unsure as to what commands I would use to actually create rectangles with those vertices.

Any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit for more information: (UPDATED)

For example:

[[0,1,1,0]
[0,0,1,1]]

are the four vertices for the first rectangle, representing (0,0) (1,0), (1,1), (0,1); in general, if the order of vertices is [a,b,c,d] they should be joined to form edges ab, bc, cd, da.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Something like this (for 2 rectangles)?  `[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]`

Comment: @batFINGER Yes, Matrix1 is exactly like that, but just for 1000 rectangles instead of just 2. My question is how would I go about setting those coordinates as the position of the vertices?

Comment: One mesh or separate mesh object per rectangle?  Also do you know about the vert order? eg if the verts are  [a, b, c, d] will the edges be [ab, bc, cd, da] ?  Perhaps edit q with some sample data.

Comment: I added some details to the question. Please let me know if there's any additional information required.

Answer (score 1):

This Code will create the mesh object with your faces.
As for the Colors you will have to decide how you want to store them.
With a different material per face?
With vertex colors?
In an image (UVMapping)?
It depends on what you want to do with your Object as to which answer is best for you.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

vertlist = [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)],
            [(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2)]]

def create_mesh_object(context, vertlist):
    bm = bmesh.new()

    for faceverts in vertlist:
        bm_verts = []
        for vert in faceverts:
            bm_verts.append(bm.verts.new((vert[0], vert[1], 0)))
        bm.faces.new(bm_verts)

    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name='MyMesh')
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name='MyObject', object_data=me)
    bm.to_mesh(ob.data)
    context.scene.objects.link(ob)

create_mesh_object(bpy.context, vertlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code will create default plane primitive, then add a copy to scene, located and scaled to match each of your rectangles.  This way all will share one mesh.

**(Assuming there's no rotation involved and that each is a rectangle)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
#define some rectangles
rectangles = [[(-1, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1)],
              [(9, -1), (11, -1), (9, 1), (11, 1)],
              [(0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 9), (3, 9)]] 

# add a plane
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
plane = context.active_object
# copy plane to each rect.
for rect in rectangles:
    r = plane.copy()
    verts = [Vector(v) for v in rect]
    # location and scale for copy from data.
    r.location.xy = sum(verts, Vector((0, 0))) / 4
    r.scale.xy = ((verts[0] - verts[1]).length / 2,
             (verts[1] - verts[3]).length / 2)
    #link to scene           
    scene.objects.link(r)
# remove initial plane
scene.objects.unlink(plane)
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: mathutils.Vector()" upon running your code, in your 16th line (with the for v in rect). Could you please advise me as to what I should do?

Comment: @Ishan With just the code above, no edits, blender version 2.77?  Have you added your own data, Vector(3) for instance will throw a type error.

Comment: verts = [Vector(v) for v in rect] # This line gave me a TypeError: mathutils.Vector() ; yes, I'm using Blender 2.77. Is there some way I could send my code to you?

Comment: Notice the difference between `[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]` and `[[0,1,1,0], [0,0,1,1]]` .. if you are using data of this form it is what is causing the error.  You edited the question and changed to this format 2hrs ago.

Comment: I made adjustments, and converted my data of the latter form to the form you used (it's now in [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]] form)

Comment: Is it working Ok now?  You can always paste sample code either in the question or at http://pasteall.org  Another format could  be `[(x,y), h, w]`  ie location, height and width. Would need to change code accordingly.

Comment: No, still getting the same error on line 210: http://www.pasteall.org/71664

Comment: Put a `print(rect)` statement before 210.  If it isn't of the form `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]` then you will need to edit YOUR code accordingly.

Comment: I found the mistake. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: I had a small follow up question; say I multiplied the vertices by the rotation matrix. How would the code change?